# Weird rectangular artifacts when using Radeon ProRender

Tags: rendering, artifacts, radeon-prorender-render-engine

Any ideas why in viewport or rendering, I get these lighter colored artifacts on my screen? I tried disabling my GPU for render, but still happens.

[image]

Comment: Could you include more details about your system specs?

Comment: Sure! 

OS: Windows 10 pro
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor, 3400 Mhz, 
GPU: RX 580 8gb
RAM: 16gb

Also wanna add that when I switch the quality to "Legacy" it's able to remove the artifacts and apply shadows correctly

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem that looks pretty much like yours. Sounds stupid, but i fixed it by simply upscaling number of samples to 256. System specs: i3 8100, rx580 4gb 16gb ram windows 10 pro 1909.